# HADOOP - Unable to initialize MapOutputCollector org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i have a problem with my code, this is my error:

> Unable to initialize MapOutputCollector org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double

i don't know from where. this is my class code where i setting up all job:

```
        conf.set("stripped", stripped);

        /* Creating the job object for the Hadoop processing */  
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "calculate error map reduce"); 

        /* Creating Filesystem object with the configuration */  
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);  

        /* Check if output path (args[1])exist or not */  
        if (fs.exists(new Path(output))) {  
            /* If exist delete the output path */  
            fs.delete(new Path(output), true);  
        }
        // Setting Driver class  
        job.setJarByClass(StrippedPartition.class);  

        // Setting the Mapper class  
        job.setMapperClass(MapperCalculateError.class);  

        // Setting the Reducer class  
        job.setReducerClass(ReduceCalculateError.class);  

        // Setting the Output Key class per il mapper 
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Double.class);  
        // Setting the Output value class per il mapper
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
```

this is my mapper class:

```
    public static class MapperCalculateError extends Mapper<Object, Text, Double, DoubleWritable>{

        private final static DoubleWritable error1 = new DoubleWritable(1.0);
        private double error,max;
        private ObjectBigArrayBigList<LongBigArrayBigList> Contain = new ObjectBigArrayBigList<LongBigArrayBigList>();
        private ObjectBigArrayBigList<LongBigArrayBigList> Stripped = new ObjectBigArrayBigList<LongBigArrayBigList>();


        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            String stripped = conf.get("stripped");
            Stripped = new Gson().fromJson(stripped.toString(), ObjectBigArrayBigList.class);



            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            Contain = new Gson().fromJson(value.toString(), ObjectBigArrayBigList.class);

            //stuff in map function, i avoid in this exeple because is not important    
            }
            context.write(max,error1);

        }
```

and this is my reduce class:

```
    public static class ReduceCalculateError extends Reducer<Double, DoubleWritable, Double, Double>{

        private double massimo=0;
        private double errore=0;

        //public ReduceCalculateError() {} 

        public void reduce(double max, Iterable<DoubleWritable> error, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            double sum=0;


            //other stuff that i avoid 

            context.write(this.massimo,sum);


        }
```

i'dont know where is the error, map and reduce is never runing, beacuse it show me map: 0% reduce: 0%

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you have `Double` you need to use `DoubleWritable`. This is because Hadoop doesn't know how to serialise `Double`, but does know how to serialise `DoubleWritable`.

Any time you do a `context.write(...)` you need to ensure that both arguments are `Writable`. For example, your map output is `context.write(max,error1);` but `max` is a `Double`, when it should be a `DoubleWritable`.

Comment: thanks! now i don't have anymore that problem! now i have other problem but i think i can fix that :D